# Type of different array declarations

Tags: c++, c

What is the type of the array declarations below? Who can say clearly for me what value in case?

```
int main() {
    int* arr[3];
    int(*arr)[3];
    int*(arr[3]);
}
```

Comment: http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Comment: The first and the third are the same.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) to help out:

- `int *arr[3]` gives "declare arr as array 3 of pointer to int".
- `int (*arr)[3]` gives "declare arr as pointer to array 3 of int"
- `int*(arr[3])` gives "declare arr as array 3 of pointer to int".

Also, of course these are not "real" declarations; there's no terminating semicolons and you can't have three variables called `arr` in the same scope.

Answer (score 3):

It’s generally a good idea to know the language you use instead of relying on tools to decipher the source code, so I do not recommend using C declaration analyzers.

---

An easy way to remember the precedence is to remember the signature of `main`, namely

```
auto main( int argc, char* argv[] )
    -> int
```

… where you know that `argv` is an array of pointers (or technically a pointer to the first element of such an array: the declaration decays to `char** argv`).

That means that given `argv` you can index it to get a pointer, `argv[i]`, and then dereference the result to get a `char`, so that the equivalent parenthesized declaration is

```
char* (argv[])
```

---

The declaration

```
char (*b)[3]
```

means that by dereferencing `b`, i.e. `*b`, you get an array that can be indexed, `(*b)[]`, and so `b` is a pointer to an array.

It’s not a pointer to the first item of such an array. It’s a pointer to *the array itself*. Hence adding 1 to `b` gives you a pointer to a following array of the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Postfix operators such as `[]` and function call `()` have higher precedence than unary `*`, so a declaration like `*a[N]` will be parsed as `*(a[N])`, or "N-element array of pointer".  To declare a "pointer to N-element array", you need to explicitly group the unary `*` with the array name, or `(*a)[N]`.

Here's a handy chart.

```
T a[N]         -- N-element array of T
T *a[N]        -- N-element array of pointer to T
T (*a)[N]      -- pointer to N-element array of T
T f()          -- function returning T
T *f()         -- function returning pointer to T
T (*f)()       -- pointer to function returning T
```

You can combine the above into pretty complex declarations:

```
T (*a[N])()       -- N-element array of pointers to functions returning T
T (*f())[N]       -- Function returning pointer to N-element array of T
T (*(*f())[N])[M] -- Function returning pointer to N-element array of pointer 
                       to M-element array of T
```

When reading a hairy declaration, start with the leftmost identifier and work your way out, remembering the rules above:

```
      f           -- f
      f()         -- is a function returning ("()" has higher precedence than "*")
     *f()         -- a pointer to
    (*f())[N]     -- an N-element array of
   *(*f())[N]     -- pointers to
  (*(*f())[N])[M] -- M-element arrays of
T (*(*f())[N])[M] -- T
```